# turning decompiled C++ code into writable C++

Tags: c++, dll

Here's my scenario I currently have a DLL that was made in like 2003 archived that has data and functions I still need to use and I'm also 90% sure the DLL doesn't work correctly as its too outdated. (Don't worry this is free software not under any license anymore).

### Good news:

I already decompiled the code to C++ code (I got the assembly code to work as well but then I have no idea how to call the functions I need from C++ so I'm choosing to work with the decompiled C++ code).

### The problem:

How do I convert the decompiled C++ code to writable C++ code as the decompiled C++ code is practically machine C++ code. I know there have been similar questions but no clear solutions.

### To provide a diagram as to where my problem is check below:

(outdated)DLL > Disassembled ASM > Disassembled C++ nearly 85% writable but uses Qword Dword, precision integers like int32 or int64. > convert to writable C++ code

If you know any software that can translate decompiled C++ code into writable C++ that would be helpful as I have gotten too close to making this work.

Answer (score 1):

> If you know any software that can translate decompiled C++ code into writable C++

there is absolutely no software that would immediately generate a writable C/C++ listing, just as there is no such software that would replace or do the work of a reverse engineer.

[Hex-Rays decompiler](https://hex-rays.com/) does not create a writable C/C++ listing. It creates pseudocode that the reverse engineer must KNOW and BE ABLE to translate into a writable listing.

Comment: Look man I'm not happy doing this I actually got the assembly code to recompile no problem at this point I'm forced to use C++ as there no command for C++ to read assembly data for functions unless you heard of one as then I would be done with this conversation this would be a complete 1 off for me.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with previous answer of @rce, but would like to provide a bit more details regarding why is it really so.

Let's assume that the initial code of this DLL was wrote in C++ and then was compiled as DLL. During the compilation the following information was **completely and almost unrecoverably lost** (if you don't have the corresponding .pdb file with debug information or RTTI inside):

- function names (part of which can be recovered from mangling data, but still)
- data types such as structures and classes (both names, inheritance if it was used and internal layout)
- Templates data
- Inline functions

Reverse engineering of C++ code is recovering this information from the usage context.

> there is **absolutely no software** that would immediately generate a
> writable C/C++ listing

here means that you can not automatically generate the lost information out of nothing, so you'll need to perform some reverse engineering manually.